# HttpUrlConnection gets Closed when InputStream Ends without explicit disconnect

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

In this piece of code i am trying to read the response from different connections made to a localhost server.
Interestingly enough, in my code

1. Connections automatically gets disconnected or resources are freed as soon as I read the whole inputStream
2. Connections don't get automatically disconnected and we have to explicitly close the connections in case we don't read the whole inputStream. This is expected

Is this (1) behaviour expected from this code and if yes then why ?

Here is the code for the client:

```
public class UrlConnectionHttpClient {

    static List<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            call(i);
        }
    }

    private static void read(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            Integer a = in.read();
            if (a == -1) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    static Thread call(final int i) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    URL l = new URL("http://localhost:8020/?q=" + i);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) l.openConnection();
                    System.out.println("starting to execute + " + i);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setReadTimeout(1000 * 1000);
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "avro/binary");
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    read(inputStream);
                    //inputStream.close();
                    //connection.disconnect();
                    //list.add(connection.getInputStream());
                    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //System.out.println("finished to execute + " + i + " and time taken is: " + (t2 - ti) + " time is: " +  System.currentTimeMillis() + " and size is: " + list.size());
                    Thread.sleep(100000);
                    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        return t;
    }
}
```

`

And this is the output from the tcpdump for the port on server.
We can clearly see from the tcpdump that the localhost server is receiving fin packets.

```
12:26:46.079516 IP localhost.54880 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [.], ack 65, win 12757, options [nop,nop,TS val 429721894 ecr 429721894], length 0
12:26:46.079527 IP localhost.54880 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [.], ack 9887, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429721894 ecr 429721894], length 0
12:26:56.092276 IP localhost.54879 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [F.], seq 119, ack 9887, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429721893], length 0
12:26:56.092318 IP localhost.54881 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [F.], seq 119, ack 9887, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429721893], length 0
12:26:56.092333 IP localhost.54878 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [F.], seq 119, ack 9887, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429721894], length 0
12:26:56.092339 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54879: Flags [.], ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.092350 IP localhost.54877 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [F.], seq 119, ack 9887, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429721893], length 0
12:26:56.092353 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54881: Flags [.], ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.092362 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54878: Flags [.], ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.092363 IP localhost.54880 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [F.], seq 119, ack 9887, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429721894], length 0
12:26:56.092379 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54877: Flags [.], ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.092390 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54880: Flags [.], ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731883 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.094884 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54877: Flags [F.], seq 9887, ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731885 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.095051 IP localhost.54877 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [.], ack 9888, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731885 ecr 429731885], length 0
12:26:56.095483 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54878: Flags [F.], seq 9887, ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731885 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.095561 IP localhost.54878 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [.], ack 9888, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731885 ecr 429731885], length 0
12:26:56.095935 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54881: Flags [F.], seq 9887, ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731886 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.095984 IP localhost.54881 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [.], ack 9888, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731886 ecr 429731886], length 0
12:26:56.096413 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54879: Flags [F.], seq 9887, ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731886 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.096474 IP localhost.54879 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [.], ack 9888, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731886 ecr 429731886], length 0
12:26:56.096873 IP localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc > localhost.54880: Flags [F.], seq 9887, ack 120, win 12755, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731886 ecr 429731883], length 0
12:26:56.096936 IP localhost.54880 > localhost.intu-ec-svcdisc: Flags [.], ack 9888, win 12450, options [nop,nop,TS val 429731886 ecr 429731886], length 0
```

Also from **lsof** output it was clear that there are no connections.

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behaviour.

Isn't it good that the `InputStream` sends the finish request to the server if there is nothing extra to be received? I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: It is obviously good. But every documentation that i have seen does specify to close the inputStream and HttpurlConnection Explicitly.

Comment: It is good to free up the resources as soon as possible. Otherwise it will be done by the garbage collector in a later time.

Comment: As i said above it is obviously good to free up resources. Currently in my above excerpt it is not being done by GC that is because i have a Thread.Sleep in my code and tcpdump has been taken during that duration.